# Case statement in Having clause in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a stored procedure where I have to check compare some result on bases of operator. operator could be either '`>`' or '`<`'
My Query is:

```
  SELECT COUNT(LastWeekId) , COUNT(PreviousToLastWeekId)
        FROM 
        (
        SELECT `transaction_id`  AS LastWeekId, NULL AS PreviousToLastWeekId
        FROM `kwt_transaction`
        WHERE `statusid` =1000            
        AND (createdon BETWEEN CONCAT(DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 7 DAY)," 00:00:00") AND CONCAT(DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 1 DAY)," 23:59:59"))
    UNION

        SELECT  `transaction_id` AS LastWeekId, NULL AS PreviousToLastWeekId
        FROM `kwt_transactions_p2p`
        WHERE `statusid` =1000            
        AND (createdon BETWEEN CONCAT(DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 7 DAY)," 00:00:00") AND CONCAT(DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 1 DAY)," 23:59:59"))
        UNION                   
        SELECT NULL AS LastWeekId, `transaction_id` AS PreviousToLastWeekId
        FROM `kwt_transaction`
        WHERE `statusid` =1000            
        AND (createdon BETWEEN CONCAT(DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 14 DAY)," 00:00:00") AND CONCAT(DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 8 DAY)," 23:59:59"))
    UNION   
        SELECT NULL AS LastWeekId, `transaction_id` AS PreviousToLastWeekId
        FROM `kwt_transactions_p2p`
        WHERE `statusid` =1000            
        AND (createdon BETWEEN CONCAT(DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 14 DAY)," 00:00:00") AND CONCAT(DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 8 DAY)," 23:59:59"))
    ) ttable
    HAVING COUNT(LastWeekId) > COUNT(PreviousToLastWeekId)
```

So I wants to check:

```
HAVING Case _operaotr
       when '>'    
       COUNT(LastWeekId) > COUNT(PreviousToLastWeekId);
when '<'
    COUNT(LastWeekId) < COUNT(PreviousToLastWeekId);
End Case;
```

Is this possible in mysql

Comment: Where does the operator come from? From a column, parameter or something?

Comment: it will come as stored procedure parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do this:

```
HAVING CASE @Operator
    WHEN '>' THEN COUNT(LastWeekId) > COUNT(PreviousToLastWeekId)
    WHEN '<' THEN COUNT(LastWeekId) < COUNT(PreviousToLastWeekId)
    WHEN '=' THEN COUNT(LastWeekId) = COUNT(PreviousToLastWeekId)
    -- and so on
END
```

Comment: working but not so pretty solution Salman. I will also have to check with > , >=, <,<= and = operators

Comment: For `=` you need something different.

Comment: Nice hack Salman. At the moment my first priority was less then and greater then operators.Thanks

Comment: See revised answer. It turns out, the query suggested in your question actually works.

Comment: yes just one different thing is that I am using End Case which still giving compile time error
If i just use End it works